# How to manage huge amount of socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have developed a C software which uses different loops to open socket on a IP and port (for example 192.168.1.10 port = 80), and check if someone is opened;
Here is the code:

```
 #include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>



int main(void)
{
    int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");

    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    int i;
    char buf[15];

    for (i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "192.168.1.%d", i); // puts string into buffer
        for (int port = 0; port<=1024; port++) {
//            Problem
//            int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
//            char recvBuff[1024];
//            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
//            
//            memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
//            if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
//            {
//                printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
//                return 1;
//            }
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
            serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(buf);
            if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
            {
               // printf("The port %d of host %s is not open \n",port,buf);

            }else{
                printf("The port %d of host %s is open \n",port,buf);
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this second version I've added the connection_nonblocking method, which reduce the possible problems available.
This is the version which uses the OpenMP directive to improve performances; do you have any idea to improve it ?

```
    #include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>


int connect_nonblock (int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *saptr, socklen_t salen)
{
    int n, valopt;
    socklen_t len;
    fd_set rset;
    struct timeval tv;
    long int arg;

    arg = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, NULL);
    arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);

    n = connect(sockfd, saptr, salen);

    if (n == 0) {
        // completed immediately
        arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
        fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
        close(sockfd);

        return 0;
    }

    if (n < 0) {
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            // fail somehow...
            arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
            fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
            close(sockfd);
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            tv.tv_sec = 0;
            tv.tv_usec = 10000;
            FD_ZERO(&rset);
            FD_SET(sockfd, &rset);
            n = select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &rset, NULL, &tv);
            if (n < 0 && errno != EINTR) {
                arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                close(sockfd);
                return -1;
            }
            else if (n > 0) {
                len = sizeof(int);
                getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &len);
                if (valopt != 0) {
                    arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                    close(sockfd);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                close(sockfd);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int i, port;
    char buf[15];
    double end, start = omp_get_wtime();
    for (i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "192.168.1.%d", i); // puts string into buffer
        fprintf(stdout, "Checking address: %s\n", buf);
        //omp_set_num_threads(1);
        #pragma omp parallel for private(sockfd,serv_addr,port)

        for (port = 0; port <= 1024; port++) {
            if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
            {
                perror("socket");
            }

            memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
            serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(buf);

            if (connect_nonblock(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
                /* uncoment this but if you want */
                //fprintf(stdout, "The port %d of host %s is not open.\n", port, buf);
                ;
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stdout, "The port %d of host %s is open.\n", port, buf);
            }
        }

    }
    end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Elapsed time = %f sec\n", end-start);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a suggestion: i think you meant `memset(recvBuff, 0 ,sizeof(recvBuff));`

Comment: You can't call connect repeatedly on the same socket after it has successfully connected.  You either need to create a new socket after each successful connection (and keep track of all of them) or close the existing one and re-create it.  In the former case, you will likely run out of file descriptors if you have lots of machines in that network.  If the call to connect seems to be hanging, then the target machine either doesn't exist or isn't answering and you aren't getting ICMP messages telling you this quickly.  Instead, the call to connect will eventually timeout after a long while.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't fully understand how to close and re-open the socket. Could you modify the code I have post with these operations ?

Comment: i think you are asking for typical `epoll` example.

Comment: Google for [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem); learn about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) & [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you are not closing socket. You can use [close](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) as this is a file descriptor. But if you scan a lot of addresses it will be time consuming if connect fails with timeout.
I am adding your code a little bit revised:

```
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

 int connect_nonblock (int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *saptr, socklen_t salen)
    {
        int n, valopt;
        socklen_t len;
        fd_set rset;
        struct timeval tv;
        long int arg;

        arg = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, NULL);
        arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
        fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);

        n = connect(sockfd, saptr, salen);

        if (n == 0) {
            /* completed immediately */
            arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
            fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
            close(sockfd);

            return 0;
        }

        if (n < 0) {
            if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
                /* fail somehow... */
                arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                close(sockfd);
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                tv.tv_sec = 0;
                tv.tv_usec = 10000;
                FD_ZERO(&rset);
                FD_SET(sockfd, &rset);
                n = select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &rset, NULL, &tv);
                if (n < 0 && errno != EINTR) {
                    arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                    close(sockfd);
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (n > 0) {
                    len = sizeof(int);
                    getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &len);
                    if (valopt != 0) {
                        arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                        fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                        close(sockfd);
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
                    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
                    close(sockfd);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }

        arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
        fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, arg);
        close(sockfd);

        return 0;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
        char recv_buff[1024];
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        int i, port;
        char buf[15];

        memset(recv_buff, '0', sizeof(recv_buff));

        for (i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
            sprintf(buf, "192.168.88.%d", i); // puts string into buffer
            for (port = 0; port <= 1024; port++) {
                if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("socket");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
                serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
                serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(buf);

                if (connect_nonblock(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                {
                    printf("The port %d of host %s is not open \n", port, buf);
                } else {
                    printf("The port %d of host %s is open \n", port, buf);
                }

                // you missed this
                close(sockfd);
             }
         }
         return 0;
     }
```

I am adding a non blocking approach using select with a very little timeout and threads. Should be remade because a lot of error checking is not done in a proper way. But hopes you will get the idea.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The problem is still there, I mean the search is stopped after some loop, and after a while, It starts again. How Can I modify it, with a continuous search ? Also, can you provide some hint for a use under OpenMP to speed-up it?

Comment: The program stops and runs slower because of the connect timeout. As in man page of connect: "Note that for IP sockets the timeout may be very long...". I've never used OpenMPI. But also I think it can be done with nonblocking sockets and select or epoll.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So the problem is that some socket stops the execution of the program, isn't it ? How can I abort them in my code. Can you modify it ?

Comment: Thank you ! You made a very good job ! Now it is just a time problem. What do you think about the use of thread ? I mean it is better to use different thread for different ports but some IP, or different IP for the same port ? Also, is there any library in C to check if a host is pingable ? In this case it will reduce more the time !

Comment: You can check if host is pingable with [liboping](http://noping.cc/#documentation) but if host is blocking ICMP request it does not mean that ports are closed. You have to check thread library and to chose what will be more convenient to you.

Comment: About the ICMP you are right. I have implemented the OpenMP, but it seems that something it is not correct. The first ip's ports are correct, but later it seems not to found it correctly. Where do you think is the problem ?

Comment: I added threads and it should scan your network for a pretty reasonable time.

Comment: Thank you for your job. Now the program it is after with the use of thread. In all case, my program should use OpenMP. I don't why, but it seems some times not to found some ports.

Comment: Can you provide some help about your code that you put ? What is the variable n means in the first function ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: With variable `n` I am just checking return status of used functions.

Comment: Thank you. What about the method connect(sockfd,...,....) ? Why does return -1,0,1 ? I've not understand the 3 cases (0,-1,1) and why use tv.tv_usec = 10000; is 10 msec timeout ? Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: `connect` can return 0 or -1, `-1` is an error but in this case (socket  is nonblocking) and the connection cannot be completed immediately - EINPROGRESS so we use select for completion. I think 10ms is fast enough for required task.

Comment: So -1 or 1 is error and 0 means that the port is opened ? Why and how can be sure that the opening of a socket is not blocking ? What is arg |= O_NONBLOCK; ? Thank you again, you're awesome !

Comment: No, it only can return `0` - success, `-1` - error, from [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect): If the connection or binding succeeds, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. With `arg |= O_NONBLOCK` and after this `fcntl` we are setting socket to nonblocking mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89287/discussion-between-i-love-coding-and-taliezin).

Answer (score 0):

Here my advise:

- Use non-blocking operations.
- Run a number of sockets at a time with controlled timeout.

There are several issues when running stream sockets: their number is finite. Old implementations can't open more than 65K sockets per interface. Newer ones can do better, but that's still a lot of resources (as you are planning to scan 260+K sockets totally).

Stream sockets do not have synchronous operations (by default). Both open and close operation initiate a sequence of packets so that both ends would be aware. You can enforce them close, of course, but that might cause problems to your algorithm as well, as kernel would still be receiving packets for those improperly terminated connections.

Even when you scan local network, the time to try to connect may be pretty high because remote host might have ICMP response disable.

So, the algorithm might look like:

```
while (true)
{
    while (size_of_socket_table < N && has_more_addr())
    {
        Create socket entry
            Create socket
            Mark operation expiration time
        Initiate connect operation
        if fail
        {
            continue
        }
        Add entry to table
        Register entry for `pollfd`
     }

    If entry table is empty
       break
    Compute timeout from socket entries
    Execute EPOLL with timeout

    Process connected sockets:
       close
       release socket entries
    Process timed out socket entries
       close
       release socket entries
}
```

Note: stream socket is connected, when file descriptor becomes ready for writing (`EPOLLOUT`).

Why `epoll` vs `poll` vs `select`?

- `epoll` allows association of user data with file descriptor (socket), which is very convenient for programming.
- `select` is not too good, as you will have to deal with FD_SET size restrictions, and it anyway uses `poll` inside.
- `poll` is good and stable, but it's your choice.

Useful links:

- http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux